# Batch music directory rename script/command for Linux (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-rename

I have a lot of directories which have as name: (YYYY) Artist - Album

Some examples:

```
(2009) Vengaboys - Greatest Hits!
(2010) AC_DC - Iron Man 2
(2014) Simon & Garfunkel - The Complete Albums Collection
(2014) Various Artists - 100 Hits Acoustic
(2015) Various Artists - Graspop Metal Meeting 1996-2015
```

How can I best batch rename those directories to following template Artist - Album (YYYY)?

Thus above output should become:

```
Vengaboys - Greatest Hits! (2009)
AC_DC - Iron Man 2 (2010)
Simon & Garfunkel - The Complete Albums Collection (2014)
Various Artists - 100 Hits Acoustic (2014)
Various Artists - Graspop Metal Meeting 1996-2015 (2015)
```

Directories not having a (YYYY) prefix should not be modified.

Could someone help me with a linux bash script or sed command to make this happen?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jens

Comment: @Jens is right. Please post what you have done so far to solve this. If you want us to help, you should try to help yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with spaces and parentheses can be rather tricky with bash.  I would use perl for this:

**rename.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

opendir my $dh, "./" or die "Unable to opendir : $!";
for my $dir ( readdir($dh) ) {
    # Skip anything that is not a directory matching '(YYYY) Name' 
    next unless -d "./$dir" and $dir =~ m|^(\(\d{4}\))\s(.*)$|;
    my $new_name = "$2 $1";
    print "'$dir' -> '$new_name'\n";
    rename $dir, $new_name
    or die "Unable to rename '$dir' to '$new_name' : $!";
}
```

Generally, life is made easier by sticking to file/directory names without spaces or special characters.  Here is how to use it:

```
$ ls
(2009) Vengaboys - Greatest Hits!
(2010) AC_DC - Iron Man 2
(2014) Simon & Garfunkel - The Complete Albums Collection
(2014) Various Artists - 100 Hits Acoustic
(2015) Various Artists - Graspop Metal Meeting 1996-2015
rename.pl

$ perl rename.pl
'(2009) Vengaboys - Greatest Hits!' -> 'Vengaboys - Greatest Hits! (2009)'
'(2010) AC_DC - Iron Man 2' -> 'AC_DC - Iron Man 2 (2010)'
'(2014) Simon & Garfunkel - The Complete Albums Collection' -> 'Simon & Garfunkel - The Complete Albums Collection (2014)'
'(2014) Various Artists - 100 Hits Acoustic' -> 'Various Artists - 100 Hits Acoustic (2014)'
'(2015) Various Artists - Graspop Metal Meeting 1996-2015' -> 'Various Artists - Graspop Metal Meeting 1996-2015 (2015)'

$ ls
AC_DC - Iron Man 2 (2010)
Simon & Garfunkel - The Complete Albums Collection (2014)
Various Artists - 100 Hits Acoustic (2014)
Various Artists - Graspop Metal Meeting 1996-2015 (2015)
Vengaboys - Greatest Hits! (2009)
rename.pl
```